# How to draw a line in android?

Tags: android

I found some code for line drawing but it doesn't work. Can any one help me to draw a line in android?

here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutmain">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my code for class:

```
 public class DrawPoints extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
     static int i = 0;
     static float static_x = 0;
     static float static_y = 0;
     static float static_x1 = 0;
     static float static_y1 = 0;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         View topLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.layoutmain);
         // register for events for the view, previously
         topLayout.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         String tag = null;

         if (i == 0) {
             static_x = event.getX();
             static_y = event.getY();
             i = 1;
         } else {
             static_x1 = event.getX();
             static_y1 = event.getY();

         }

         if (i == 1) {
             Paint p = new Paint();
             p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
             p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
             Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
             canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

             canvas.drawLine(static_x, static_y, static_x1, static_y1, p);
             i = 0;
         }
         return false;
     }

 }
```

Comment: You can also refer to this example which is demo of 2d graphics: [Android 2d graphics demo](http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/2d-graphics-example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this code provided in Android Samples.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html

Answer (score 14):

You can simply write this in your xml layout:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" />
```

This will create a horizontal line.

Comment: ok you put this View but i don't require this as you can see i want to draw line in any point where you user touch two point of screen at that time one straight line will be draw in Canvas or on any view.

Comment: That's some wicked lateral thinking

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution with little trick, that improve **Draw performance** faster than **163 times** when compare with penchoco solution:

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_line"
</View>
```

The only difference thing with [penchoco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978688/289277) solution is used [9 patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqyt0.png) [image: Click here to download 9 patch image] drawable 1x1 pixel instead of color.

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_line"
```

**Question:**
Could anyone explain why using 9 patch image performance was improve more than 163 times, which implement behind scenario that make a magic result ?

Thanks

Comment: for more response for your question you can ask new question for this .by that way other can also see the question.